# input type=search don't accept height

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to make an `input type="search"` tall but CSS don't affect it. My code is like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="search" />
```

CSS:

```
input{width:100%; height:100px;}
```

But it doesn't work. Take a look at fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KNu3s/1/)

Comment: What browser are you testing in? It works just fine in Firefox 6.0 for example.

Comment: It works for me; both inputs are the same size. Chromium 12.

Comment: Also in Internet Explorer 9, Opera 11.50 and Chrome 13.

Comment: I'm chrome 13 Macm and Safari Mac, Also iPhone simulator

Comment: I think he mean the 100px height which isn't the height of the search field.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

See http://trentwalton.com/2010/07/14/css-webkit-appearance/

Webkit defaults (hijacks) to using a native search field, but you can override it with:

```
-webkit-appearance:none;
```

Comment: Awesome! Just in case, is there any way to make that x button inside it bigger?

Comment: @Mohsen - i'm just guessing really but i'd say that because it is a native gui component you can't style it with css at all.

Answer (score 16):

```
-webkit-appearance:textfield;
box-sizing: content-box;
```

http://tonibarrett.com/forcing-my-style-onto-input-typesearch/

this solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way imho to change type 'search' to type 'text' or drop web-kit-appearance as mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

You must write

```
 input[type="search"]{width:100%; height:100px;}
```

instead of

```
input{width:100%; height:100px;}
```